# Sharing a semaphore or other java object over a cluster using standard JDK libraries

Tags: java, networking, shared

Is there a native JDK solution for storing objects in memory, over a network? In particular, a way to share and synchronize a semaphore ?

Comment: I know it's not exactly what your looking for, but netflix has an example of creating a shared semaphore using Zookeeper+Curator. https://github.com/Netflix/curator/wiki/Shared-Semaphore

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use [ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/), it has excellent support for remote lock management.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what exactly you mean by "native JDK solution". [Netflix Curator](https://github.com/Netflix/curator), a rich client for [ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/), is pure Java and has a [cross-JVM Semaphore implementation](https://github.com/Netflix/curator/wiki/Shared-Semaphore) which does exactly what it sounds like: providing shared leases across all participating JVMs. Curator is [available in Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3a%22curator%22) if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Java RMI: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html

I think it should be able to provide synchronisation over the net. If you don't want to use a server like Zookeeper, this is the best solution I can think of.

Comment: "I think it should be able to provide..."? Can you give some reference for that? I'm not very familiar with RMI, but I'm not aware of anything it does that would help in this area.

Comment: @RyanStewart It's been a while for me as well. I could think of a class that implements the "Remote" interface which has methods called "lock" and "unlock", applying a lock to a private semaphore. This method would have to be made accessible to the remote side - voilà.

Comment: Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: No, I see what you mean. I thought you meant RMI itself provided some kind of synchronization protocol.

Comment: @RyanStewart No, it doesn't.